# Angularjs extending services and inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, extend, angularjs-service

I am trying to find of a way to extend services in angular. I am not sure if angular has a concept of extending or if it merely relies on injection for code reuse. So what I have tried so far are the following

**Method 1**

```
myApp.factory('myFactory', function ($http) {
   return{
     common: function(){
      console.log('I am from myFactory');
     }
});


 myApp.factory('myFactory1', function (myFactory) {
    return {
     common: myFactory.common
    };
});
```

**OR**

```
 myApp.factory('myFactory1', function (myFactory) {
    return angular.extend(myFactory, {
     common: function() {
      console.log('I am form Factory1')
      }
    });
});
```

Both approaches sort of work OK but my main issue is how to call the parent. i.e. something like this:

**in myFactory1**

```
     common: function(){
      console.log('I am from myFactory1');
      this.prototype.common.apply(this, arguments);
     }
```

I want is to print out 'I am from myFactory1', 'I am from myFactory'

Generally Is this supported in angular ? Or should I take a different approach in extending /inheriting functionality?

Thank you

Comment: if it meets your requirements go ahead. angularjs services are singletons. So you should favorise composition over inheritance.

Comment: So can't call parent function with same name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I've achieved this in the past is to have the base angular service return an instance of a plain old Javascript 'class'. The extended service, then creates an instance of the base class, and uses standard JS prototypal inheritance to extend the class and returns an instance of the new extended object.

For example:

```
// Base service
app.factory('Shape', function() {

    var Shape = function(colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    };

    Shape.prototype.getColour = function() {
        return this.colour;
    };

    return Shape;
});

// Extended service
app.factory('Square', function(Shape) {

    var Square = function(colour) {
        Shape.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    Square.prototype = new Shape();

    Square.prototype.getSides = function() {
        return 4;
    };

    return Square;
});
```

Comment: The code as you have it will cause Shape's constructor to get called an extra time when Square is defined.

I would suggest that Square.prototype should be defined like:  
  
`Square.prototype = Object.extend(Shape.prototype);`  
  
Note that Object.extend is not present on all browsers, but es5-shim has a shim for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few tweaks on `Square` @romiem snippet:

```
// Extended service
app.factory('Square', function(Shape) {

    var Square = function(colour) {
        Shape.call(this, arguments);
    };

    Square.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
    Square.prototype.constructor = Square;

    Square.prototype.getSides = getSides;

    return Square;

    function getSides() {
      return 4;
    }

});
```

This snippet follows best practices and avoid the problem about create a new instance through `new Shape()`. Also in compatible with old browsers.